# Chunk array in pages, rows and columns

Tags: php, arrays, pdf-generation

I would like to display a large table in a PDF-File (horizontal orientation), on multiple pages, the data array is from my database. There should be 8 columns per page. So the result array has pages, which have rows, which contain columns.

I already tried different combinations of for loops but could not figure it out..

The Data Structure I have:

```
  $data = [
    [
      'name' => 'Item_1',
      'id' => 1243123
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'Item_2',
      'id' => 1789435
    ],
    ...
    [
      'name' => 'Item_8',
      'id' => 4513531
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'Item_9',
      'id' => 352790
    ],
    ...
    [
      'name' => 'Item_12',
      'id' => 643563
    ],
  ];
```

The Data Structure I want:

```
  $result = [
    [
      ['Item_1', 'Item_2', ... , 'Item_8'],
      [1243123, 1789435, ... , 4513531]
    ],
    [
      ['Item_9', ... , 'Item_12'],
      [352790, ... , 643563]
    ]
  ];
```

I tried it like this:

```
  $data = array_chunk($fromDatabase, 8);
  $result = [];

  $pages = count($data);

  // For each Page
  for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) {

    // Add Rows to Page
    for ($r = 0; $r < count($data[$i]); $r++) {

      $result[$p][$r][] = $data[$i][0];

    }

  }
```

and with a lot of other loop structures.

Comment: Can you show us anything you have tried?

Comment: @Bryan I've added a sample to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can separate the original data into separate arrays with [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) next, you can chunk each column array into the size you want with [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

Finally, take the two chunked arrays and combine them.

```
$nameChunks = array_chunk(array_column($data, 'name'), 8);
$idChunks = array_chunk(array_column($data, 'id'), 8);

$result = [];
foreach($nameChunks as $key => $names) {
    $result[] = [
        $names,
        $idChunks[$key],
    ];
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: What if the number of elements in data array is dynamic? Like name, id, date, street, ... ?

Comment: You would need to do the first two lines (column, chunk) for each item. You could store them in an array instead of as variables, then when putting them all in the result array, loop again to push them all into the result array.